# Debugging in RStudio throws error.

Tags: debugging, rstudio

I have an R script that doesn't throw what I expect it to.  However, it does run all the way through.  To fix it, I've tried setting a breakpoint in order to enter debug mode.

But when I do this, I get an error that says:

```
debugSource('~/mycode/konfio/Projects/Interest Rates/src/getPARS.R', echo=TRUE)
Error in if (length(funBody[[idx]]) != length(originalFunBody[[idx]]) ||  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I've Googled this error, but only found one link which didn't help. If anyone knows how to get my hands on the Debugger, or somewhere else that I can search for the problem I'll be grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio's breakpoints work by rewriting your function to include debug code. The most likely cause of this problem is a bug in RStudio that's causing it to fail to rewrite your function. There are a few possible solutions:

1. Remove just the statements you want to debug and put them into a separate function. Set the breakpoint on that function and call it from your main script.
2. Use `browser()` based-debugging: just add `browser()` where you would have set a breakpoint (RStudio's debugger works with R debugging features, too).
3. Use a newer version of RStudio. Debugging R scripts (as opposed to functions) has improved a lot lately, and if you're feeling especially brave you can try a [daily build](http://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/).

If you have time, please post the contents of the file you're having trouble with to RStudio's [support forum](https://support.rstudio.com/); we'd like to take a look and see if we can make a fix in an upcoming version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... and for the development of the software.  It got fixed before I knew where the problem was.  If I get that again, I'll remember to post in the forum.

Comment: #Jonathan I'm back with my bug.  I have posted it in RStudio, but didn't find the attachment section  o.O  Here's the link.  
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202682497-Setting-a-breakpoint-throws-error